# Wait until ajax post requests response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In my page, I have multiple checkboxes and some are mandatory to be checked.

I have the click `eventListener`, when user clicks on checkbox, I verify if it is checked then I run the `saveCheckboxValue(checkbox name,value "1");` otherwise value is `0`.
the function looks as the following:

```
function saveCheckboxValue(checkbox_name, value=0) {
    $.ajax({
        url:"/includes/ajax/saveCheckbox/",
        type: "post",
        timeout: 10000,
        data: 
        {
            'checkbox_name' : checkbox_name,
            'fieldValue': value
        },
        success: function(response) {
            if(response == "success"){
                for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
                    if(checkboxes[i]['name'] == checkbox_name){
                        checkboxes[i]['value'] = value;
                        break;
                   }
                }
                return true;
            } else {
               return false;
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

When the user clicks on next I verify in if mandatory checkboxes are checked.

```
function checkMandatory() {
    for(var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
        if(checkboxes[i]['mandatory'] && checkboxes[i]['value'] == null){
            return false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The `checkboxes` array is defined at the beginning when the user loads the page and has the fallowing columns:

```
checkboxes[
    {'checkbox_name':'name_123', 'value':null, 'mandatory':true},
    {'checkbox_name':'name_456', 'value':1, 'mandatory':false},
]
```

The main issue is when the user clicks on next or has a slow internet connection or server doesn't respond fast, It show the alert that the at least one of the mandatory checkbox is not checked. The user sees that all are checked.

I tried the `async:false`, but it is deprecated and not recommended. Also it is not user-friendly to prevent users from checking them one after another because the response from the server didn't come. I save the value for checkboxes because if the user closes the page and returns back the value must remain saved.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more detail.  You want to wait for the server to validate the input before allowing the user to continue to the next step? Should the next button be disabled while waiting for a response?

Comment: Yes, I want to wait for server validation for all checked checkboxes, they are dynamic checkboxes, there can be one or many of them. I don't want to disable the button because it will create ambiguity, as to why it is disabled. When the user clicks on the next button once again I compare the values from the `checkboxes` array with their actual values If they are not saved or validated in Backend, I run the `saveCheckboxValue` function again before checking the mandatory conditions, but before the requests responses, it runs the mandatory condition. It doesn't wait for responses.